# is there a way to save selected text when a key is presses

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program in python.

When we select some text and press a key it will save it into a `txt` file. Does someone know how to save selected text into a file in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know `file handling`? If yes, here's your answer. If no, learning it would help you solve this question. It is a concept which deals with reading and writing in a file using python. Acc to your question, we'll open a file, take an input, write that input in a file and then close the file. You should open the file in append mode (I prefer) because everytime you write in the file, nothing will effect the old data. If you open it in write mode, everytime it'll overwrite the file resulting in writing only the last data and losing the previous ones. To open the file in append mode, type "a" in the open statement. Let's say your file name is writing.txt then your code:

```
f=open("writing.txt","a")
f_input=input("Enter your text= ")
f.write(f_input)
f.close()
```

Now when you check your file, you'll see your text written

Comment: This cant work for me as i am not going to select the text in a opened file like in notepad but in the web or anywhere else like you know right we copy text like that another key to save it into the local file

Comment: You want to copy the text of a website and store it in a file right?? And you want to do this task with python?

Comment: How I understand from the description is that he wants a python script which is running in the background and every time a key is pressed, to dump the currently selected text from the browser into a file.

Comment: @manty2435 is that what you exactly want??